# How to launch a Cocoa app at login with ServiceManagement

Tags: cocoa

I'm build an agent app in Cocoa which needs to be launched at login.

I did exactly what [TIMSCHROEDER](https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/) said. It was prefect in debug mode. But, since I archived and export my app to a `macOS Application`, I can't launch it anymore.

I'm using Xcode 8.3 on macOS 10.12.4.

Comment: I can confirm that Tim's tutorial works in both debug and release mode.

Comment: @vadian thx, do you have any idea or advice for this situation? I'm a newbie to Cocoa.

Comment: Check all settings again.

Comment: yeah ,thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when I was testing launch at log in and changing the Bundle Identifier of helper app did the trick.

Try it. It will work

Comment: thx，well I did change the code sign profiles, and now it works